# Blender + SceneKit (how-to)

Tags: ios, xcode, scenekit, blender

A few questions to game developers. I am very beginner in this. I want to create a game level for example a green plane with trees. I have played a little in Blender and SceneKit. I know that I can export `.dae` from Blender and import it to Xcode. My questions:

1. Should I delete camera and light node before export? Why?
2. Should I design all level in one `.dea` file or make it separately? For example one `.dea` for plane and four different trees in for `.dea's` How to merge them in Xcode?
3. Can I use many times one `.dea` to generate for example a forest? How?
4. If creating design in separately is better way how to keep proportions between them to protect yourself from creation man bigger than tree?

I will be very great full if somebody someone dedicates to these questions. It will cut my time to learn basic. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll tell you how I do it:

1) .dea files use only for models(trees, charecters, building, etc...)

2) Game scene: floor, models, light, camera, obstacles build using Xcode scene builder or by code or mixed (based on the scene).

3) Based on size of world/level it can be split into several scenes(visible/invisible by player). Then you can create one blank scene and load/unload these scenes during runtime.

4) For a model you create a reference and after that build forest using reference of tree. If in the future you need to change the color of tree, all trees in all scenes will be updated.

5) For each model(SCNNode) (loaded from .dea file) you can set scale attribute (from code or by Xcode scene builder)

Also, [3D Apple Games by Tutorials](https://store.raywenderlich.com/products/3d-apple-games-by-tutorials) is very good for starting.